# Duplicating object aligned with and on faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers, object-mode

I'm trying to duplicate the cube in the image on the center of the faces of the torus facing inwards. I've tried a few things with curve deforms and array modifiers but couldn't get anything to work. Also I might want them to scale with the size of the face.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this didn't change in the 2.8 (I use the 2.79), choose align to view on the editing preference[image]

Then in edit mode choose the face you want your object to be aligned to
Hit shitf + 7 to get your view parallel to that face and shift D to duplicate the face (now extrude it and you have your cube.

If you need to extrude a face and have it's size to increase with the distance, do it with option + S (on mac)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your Torus <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> to set it in the same location

Hide the original Torus

[image: hide torus]

Parent the Cube to the new Torus by selecting the Cube then Shift selecting the Torus and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
[image: parenting menu]

Select the Torus and under Instancing -> Faces
[image: Instancing]

Remove any geometry where the faces of the Torus should not instance a Cube
[image: torus with edited geometry]

Untick the Display Instancer, so you can just see the instanced Cubes. 
[image: hide instancer]

Show the original Torus again.

[image: show torus]
[image: original shown]

You can continue to edit the Cube and it's instances will update in real time.
[image: cube edited]

Or edit the Torus.001 Mesh to add/remove Faces etc.

Comment: This is great, but I don't have the cubes aligned with the faces on the torus, and there seems to be some interesting transformation going on. I'd like it if they only scaled to the faces (by some factor) and stayed oriented in the same direction. https://imgur.com/a/4YNBjYf

Comment: Try Instancing on Verts instead of Faces